# Vertx: verticle is not garbage collected after undeploy

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I would like to ask if it is normal that a verticle is not GC after an undeploy.

I have an application running multiple vertciles which can be dynamicly stopped (undeployed) and started (deployed). I was profiling it to see if everything is correctly destroyed when my verticle is undeployed (+ forced GC) but I noticed that there alive references in DeploymentManager. Every time I undeploy the verticle, the number of objects increase. Is it a normal behaviour ?

[image]

Thank you for help

Michael

Comment: Can you please report a bug? Thank you

Comment: Finally I found a problem in my code. Thank you